ASP.NET Core MVC - Error - The lazily-initialized type does not have a public, parameterless constructor

Error - System.MissingMemberException: The lazily-initialized type does not have a public, parameterless constructor

Error is self explanatory. The type do not have a public, parameterless constructor.
But how do I make dependency injection in ASP.NET Core MVC to resolve to actual constructor I want?
The lazy type has a constructor with other dependencies those are registered in startup.cs. That is the constructor that I want.
I tried adding a default constructor. But I need to use the constructor with dependencies.
Application is an ASP.NET Core MVC app. I am not using Unity or any other DI frameworks, but using the one that comes with ASP.NET Core MVC.
I read in other posts that frameworks like Unity will resolve this automatically. I want to know how this can be resolved in ASP.NET Core MVC.
I have a controller that depends on a type that is lazy initialized.
SampleController:
public class SampleController
{
    private readonly Lazy<LazyTypeA> _LazyTypeA;
    
    public SampleController(LazyTypeA lazyTypeA)
    {
       _LazyTypeA = lazyTypeA;
    }
    
    public Action TestAction()
    {
      _LazyTypeA.SomeMethod()     <-- Errors at this line
    }
}

LazyTypeA:
public class LazyTypeA
{
    private readonly DependentClass _dependentClass ;

    public LazyTypeA(DependentClass dependentClass)
    {
      _dependentClass  = dependentClass ;
    }
}

Startup.cs:
services.AddTransient<DependentClass>();
services.AddTransient<Lazy<LazyTypeA>>();


"I tried adding a default constructor. But I need to use the constructor with dependencies." - <-- You haven't told us which type you added the default-constructor to - I don't know if you meant SampleController or LazyTypeA or something else.

Is _LazyTypeA.SomeMethod() meant to be an extension-method on Lazy<LazyTypeA> - or something else?

You need to register the LazyTypeA in the DI. And then I would recommend to use factory registration (otherwise the Lazy<T>(T value) ctor accepting the instance will be used which will result in the LazyTypeA being constructed upon the Lazy resolution not when first actual Lazy.Value call):
services.AddTransient<LazyTypeA>();
services.AddTransient<Lazy<LazyTypeA>>(sp => new Lazy<LazyTypeA>(() => sp.GetRequiredService<LazyTypeA>()));

Note that if you want to resolve a dependency on per-action basis then you can use the FromServicesAttribute in the action to inject action-specific dependecy:
public Action TestAction([FromServices] LazyTypeA lazyTypeA)
{
    lazyTypeA.SomeMethod();
}

Also you can look into using into something similar to what is done with the ILogger<T> registration with the factory or just wrap the above approach into set of AddLazy<T> extension methods.

Inject your services wrapper around Lazy in your controller as well:
public class SampleController
{
    private readonly Lazy<LazyTypeA> _LazyTypeA;
    
    public SampleController(Lazy<LazyTypeA> lazyTypeA)
    {
        _LazyTypeA = lazyTypeA;
    }
}

and add generic registration to allow any service to be resolved from Lazy:
services.AddTransient<DependentClass>();
services.AddTransient(typeof(Lazy<>), typeof(LazyServiceProvider<>));

using lazy service provider:
public class LazyServiceProvider<T> : Lazy<T>
    where T : class
{
    public LazyServiceProvider(IServiceProvider provider)
        : base(() => provider.GetRequiredService<T>())
    {
    }
}

Finally, usage example in the controller:
public Action TestAction()
{
    _LazyTypeA.Value.SomeMethod();
}

